# Chrome not getting the signed_request post data

Tags: php, facebook, google-chrome, post

I have a canvas app loading in an iFrame on a Facebook Page. For all browsers but Chrome (haven't personally tested IE yet) the `signed_request` variable is sent via POST. For some reason Chrome does not submit this data. I looked at the network inspector and indeed Chrome registers the POST data with the request, but when printing the contents of `$_REQUEST` there's nothing. No POST data being sent at all.

Safari and Firefox work fine. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** I noticed that Chrome does do the right thing when accessing the Facebook page via https. The problem only occurs with http. This is bizarre because I have both valid http and https URLs set in the app settings, plus the page works fine across other browsers.

Comment: Great question.  I upvoted this and will subscribe to see what you are able to find out about this.

Comment: Thanks DMCS. Here's what's up: I should have mentioned that the site hosting the Facebook canvas page utilizes an https redirect, so that any requests for http get redirected to https. However we made an exception for access to the canvas page, so that it could be accessed via http. Well, it turns out that Chrome had cached the protocol redirect and won't release it. Still haven't found a fix, but at least this only affects users who had previously been redirected, meaning most users will be fine.

Comment: What if you empty Chrome caches from chrome://net-internals/#httpCache

Answer (score 0):

chrome is bit strict at cross domain and protocol rules. try running chrome in safe mode to test if the problem is actually related to http -> https redirection