# Facebook canvas url redirected to https

Tags: facebook, canvas, https

I have a Facebook app with both, canvas url and secure canvas url.

When my user opens the app within a page tab, my app reads the `signed_request` with the `page id` and delivers content for this specific FB page.

When my user uses `https` surfing in FB logs out and the next user logs in with only `http` surfing, **my app gets redirected to the secure canvas url and my `signed_request` parameter is lost**. Without the `signed_request` parameter I can't determine which page should be served by my app.

**When I empty the browser cache**, the right http URL of my app is used.

Is there a way to always use `https` with FB apps, or prevent the browser from caching the `https` URL?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but I don't think so you have right. Your app is called by Facebook with $_POST['signed_request'] anyway. Moreover, my tab app called by Facebook via https everytime, no matter the FB page loaded via http or https.

Comment: OK, seems the problem is Chrome specific:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571339/chrome-not-getting-the-signed-request-post-data

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect from http to https and not lose the signed_request POST parameter, you can manually snag it before the redirect and append it to the URL as a GET parameter. See below!

```
// Force SSL
if(443 != $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] || 'on' != $_SERVER['HTTPS'])
{
    $queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    $hadQueryString = '' == $queryString ? false : true;
    $baseUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $questionMark = strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?');

    if(false !== $questionMark)
    {
        $baseUrl = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, $questionMark);
    }

    if($hadQueryString && isset($_REQUEST['signed_request']))
    {
        $queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] . '&signed_request=' . $_REQUEST['signed_request'];
    }
    elseif(isset($_REQUEST['signed_request']))
    {
        $queryString = 'signed_request=' . $_REQUEST['signed_request'];
    }

    $newLocation = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $baseUrl . '?' . $queryString;

    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: ' . $newLocation);
    exit();
}
```